# SIGABRT crash on OS X app

Tags: xcode, cocoa, crash-reports, sigabrt

I have had this crash that occurs rather rarely for ages. Unfortunately, I'm not able to get much hints from this received crashlog as it doesn't show any code line from my app. I believe this is related to bad memory management, but I have never managed to generate this crash in my debugger. I have tried enabling NSZombies and run this in Zombies-instruments but they have not shown the cause of the problem. Are there any other tricks I could try to find the cause for this kind of crash? Does the crashlog tell anything? Could it related to storyboard, timers or anything like that? Any hints are greatly appreciated!

```
Exception Type:  SIGABRT
Exception Codes: #0 at 0x7fff93796d42
Crashed Thread:  0
Thread 0 Crashed:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib              0x00007fff93796d42 __pthread_kill + 10
1   libsystem_c.dylib                   0x00007fff936fc420 abort + 129
2   libc++abi.dylib                     0x00007fff9225094a __cxa_bad_cast + 0
3   libc++abi.dylib                     0x00007fff92275c2f _ZL26default_unexpected_handlerv + 0
4   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x00007fff92d846fe _ZL15_objc_terminatev + 103
5   libc++abi.dylib                     0x00007fff92272d49 _ZSt11__terminatePFvvE + 8
6   libc++abi.dylib                     0x00007fff92272dc3 _ZSt9terminatev + 51
7   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff93632910 _dispatch_client_callout + 28
8   libdispatch.dylib                   0x00007fff9363faac _dispatch_main_queue_callback_4CF + 925
9   com.apple.CoreFoundation            0x00007fff7df20bc9 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_SERVICING_THE_MAIN_DISPATCH_QUEUE__ + 9
10  com.apple.CoreFoundation            0x00007fff7dee1c0d __CFRunLoopRun + 2205
11  com.apple.CoreFoundation            0x00007fff7dee1114 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 420
12  com.apple.HIToolbox                 0x00007fff7d441ebc RunCurrentEventLoopInMode + 240
13  com.apple.HIToolbox                 0x00007fff7d441cf1 ReceiveNextEventCommon + 432
14  com.apple.HIToolbox                 0x00007fff7d441b26 _BlockUntilNextEventMatchingListInModeWithFilter + 71
15  com.apple.AppKit                    0x00007fff7b9d8a54 _DPSNextEvent + 1120
16  com.apple.AppKit                    0x00007fff7c1547ee -[NSApplication(NSEvent) _nextEventMatchingEventMask:untilDate:inMode:dequeue:] + 2796
17  com.apple.AppKit                    0x00007fff7b9cd3db -[NSApplication run] + 926
18  com.apple.AppKit                    0x00007fff7b997e0e NSApplicationMain + 1237
19  libdyld.dylib                       0x00007fff93668235 start + 1
```

Comment: Any tips are welcome, even guesses.